# To type 'Double' is not valid?

Tags: c#, vb.net

Hello I am trying to make an app that will annoy my friend cause he always does this kind of stuff to me. Anyways its where I add a whole bunch of people to the call on skype so his skype will keep ringing on him xbox one xD. But the problem is I keeep getting the error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
>   Additional information: Conversion from string "/add Zapanon" to type 'Double' is not valid.

And the code I am using is

```
Dim count As Integer = +1
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0
    For i = 0 To 4
        Dim value As String = "/add Zapanon"
        'var result = string.Format("/add Zapanon{0} {Enter}", newstringg);
        value += count
        SendKeys.Send(value)

        count = count + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Now I did convert the code from C# to VB.net but I cannot find out why this is not working and would like help from someone!

Comment: have you tried changing `value += count` to  `value += count.ToString()`? VB may be complaining about trying to add a double to a string

Comment: += is an arithmetic operator when the right-hand side is a number, it doesn't mean string concatenation here.  Use Option Strict On at the top of the source code file to catch problems like this at compile-time.

Comment: @HansPassant `+` can definitely be used to concatenate strings in VB (when both operands are strings). Is `+=` behaving differently in any respect? I don't have a VB compiler at hand to try it.

Comment: `+=` does compile for strings in VB.

Comment: @LordTakkera I tried both of those but it will only go up to /add Zapanon5 then go back to /add Zapanon and it will not press the enter key to send each one ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VB.NET is a bit fishy around conversions and the slight differences between the string operators `+` and `&`.

`value += count` is actually trying to convert `value` to an integer, which it is not.

You can either use `value &= count`, or convert count to a string, e.g.: `value += CStr(count)`.

Comment: I tried both of those but it will only go up to /add Zapanon5 then go back to /add Zapanon and it will not press the enter key to send each one ?

Comment: No, there is no reason that it would. Assuming you're using `System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys`, whose [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys(v=vs.110).aspx) says that to send Enter you must use either `{Enter}` or `~` in your string. So that would rather be `"/add Zapanon5~"`

Comment: Ok so do you know why it is going only too 5

Comment: This is turning into a programming lesson, which is slightly out of topic. It goes to 5 because `count` starts at 1 and the loop is executed 5 times `For i = 0 To 4`.